# Zero sequence component in unbalanced faults rotation

Tags: electric-machine

I am trying to understand the physical/practical meaning of the zero sequence component, I referred to some books. however, I am not sure is me or are there different interpretation of the zero sequence phasor regarding whether they are rotational or not?
I know that positive sequence rotates as the original equipment rotation, whereas, negative sequence rotates in the opposite direction and thus it tends to reduce the positive sequence torque.
But, I don't know how the zero sequence contribute if it does to the rotation, does it have a torque?
I highlighted the confusing information.
The first book:
[image]
[image]

The second book:
[image]

Sources:

The first book:
TRANSIENT ANALYSIS OF ELECTRIC POWER CIRCUITS HANDBOOK
Published by Springer 2005
by
ARIEH L. SHENKMAN
ISBN-10 0-387-28797-3

The second book:
Protective Relaying Handbook, Volume 2
2009 Published by Inter National Electrical Testing Association

Comment: The first highlight says they are still rotating *phasors*, and the second says they have no *phase rotation*. That means they are phasors and all have the same magnitude and phase. But their phases are the same so they still rotate, but they have no phase rotation between them, i.e. phase1-phase2=phase2-phase3=phase3-phase1=0. Equal magnitudes, same angles. The picture `b)` from the 1st book agrees with `6.109c` from the 2nd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first highlight says they are still rotating phasors, and the second says they have no phase rotation. That means they are phasors and all have the same magnitude and phase. Their phases are the same so they still rotate, but they have no phase rotation between them, i.e. \$\phi_1-\phi_2=\phi_2-\phi_3=\phi_3-\phi_1=0\$. Equal magnitudes, same angles. The picture `b)` from the first book agrees with the formula `6.109c` from the second.